# Compiler doesn't proceed after strstok() (C++)

Tags: c++, strtok

I used `strtok()` function with a while loop and it compiled, but ANYTHING after the while loop doesn't seem to exist for the compiler:

```
int main()
{
    int j = 1;
    char a[60] = "ion ana adonia doina doinn ddan ddao . some other words ";
    char *pch[36];
    pch[0] = strtok(a, ".");
    while (pch[j + 1] != NULL)
    {
        cout << pch[j - 1] << endl;
        pch[j] = strtok(NULL, ".");
        j++;
    }
    cout << "hello!"; //this doesnt display at all
        return 0;
}
```

I am using c-free.

Comment: herohuyongtao ok edited it still nothing!

Comment: `while (pch[j + 1] ...)` is looking at uninitialized data. The first time through, you're looking at element 2, but you've only initialized element 0... and this off-by-2 continues with each iteration. Also there's nothing to stop the loop from going past `pch[35]` even though your buffer stops there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among other things, your while loop end condition is wrong. You're checking `pch[j + 1]` which is always uninitialized memory, causing the loop to continue unpredictably until you encounter a zero in memory which may cause the loop to stop.

On an alternate note, I *highly* discourage the use of `strtok` in C++, due to its string-destruction. Boost has a quite nice string parsing facility, and even in the base C++ language it's simple enough to do most parsing with built in string functionality.

Comment: Using legacy C methods for string manipulation should be strongly discouraged in general. `std::string` and friends are the safest way to handle string data. C strings are notoriously difficult to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is bizarre. Try this:

```
int main()
{
    int j = 0;
    char a[60] = "ion ana adonia doina doinn ddan ddao . some other words ";
    char *pch[36];
    pch[j] = strtok(a, ".");
    while (pch[j] != NULL)
    {
        cout << pch[j] << endl;
        pch[++j] = strtok(NULL, ".");
    }
    cout << "hello!"; //this doesnt display at all
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it is great, i think my whole problem was the difference between ++j and j++
thanks again